# Unable to install PyMySQL

Tags: python, pip, pymysql

I am trying to install PyMySQL to my computer using pip and I am getting an error message (I am using Python version 3.6). Both of the errors I am getting appear to be traced back to basecommand.py file. The first line of code in question is this one:
try:
            status = self.run(options, args)

The error message is below

```
C:\Users\Brian>pip install pymysql
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 275, in run
    build_isolation=options.build_isolation,
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'req_tracker'
```

I have literally tried coping the code from another Windows user who was able to download PyMySQL without error yet an error is appearing for me. Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: what version is your pip? @Brian

Comment: Hi Saket. It's version 18.0.

Comment: Try rollbacking it to 10 or less. @Brian